Data generation processes that "vary slowly enough"
I am considering some abstract data generation processes producing data by first drawing features $x_{1:n}\sim p(x)$ iid, and then drawing the responses $y_i\sim p(y\mid x_i)$ iid, where $p(y\mid x)$ is a family of distributions. Here $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$.
I want to consider only such families that vary "slowly enough" in $x$, so I want to impose some conditions on these families that are reasonable (in the sense that we expect to often hold "in nature"). What I came up is the following, which works for my specific use case. We require that:

For each $x^*$ the function $f(x)=\delta(p(y\mid x),p(y\mid x^*))$ is continuous in $x=x^*$, where $\delta$ is the total variation distance.

Is this kind of conditions something known and studied in the literature? Are there similar conditions that have been considered in the past?
